# How can I adjust the mouse scroll wheel sensitivity?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, ubuntu-10.04, mouse-wheel

I just replaced my old Logitech mouse with a Microsoft Wireless Laser mouse, and the scrolling is too fast for my liking.

How can I adjust the scroll sensitivity?

Update:

I just updated to 10.04, but still don't see anything.  Any changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This totally depends on which interface you are using. If you are using KDE check [this out](http://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleId=5717) <strike>if you are using Gnome check [this out](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/stable/prefs-mouse.html.en).</strike>

Currently in Gnome there is really no way to change this except in programs themselves. Example: Firefox's about:config you can change the mouse scroll by lines entry. From what I have read it is hard coded into either gtk or xorg.

For Firefox addon options a friend said [SmoothWheel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/357) works wonders for him

Comment: I'm using Gnome, but neither of those links addresses scrolling, which seems to be a hard-coded default.

Comment: @Chris updated answer with more research.

Comment: I tried the firefox settings, but even at 1, it's a bit fast.  And of course that doesn't help at all in Chrome.

Comment: @chris for chrome you can use https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn

Comment: kde link down. :<

Comment: Not even Web Archive has it... http://web.archive.org/web/20130108031801/http://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleId=5717

Answer (score 17):

I can't take credit for this, I read it somewhere else. I am running Mint 13, Cinnamon. If you are using MS Wireless:

- Boot System
- Log in
- Unplug mouse receiver from USB port
- Plug receiver back in
- Voila

Mouse Wheel scrolling set to reasonable speed.

Comment: This worked great under Lubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I can confirm this also still works under Linux Mint 14 (MATE)

Answer (score 1):

Try [resetmsmice](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resetmsmice), which will fix this problem, without having to unplug and replug the mouse receiver.
Many thanks to the author Paul F Richards, also the [Ubuntu launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/971321)

Answer (score 0):

I edited some **about:config** and works great.
(Firefox 7.0.1, with Gnome on Linux 11.04)

- mousewheel.withnokey.sysnumlines = false  (*Don't want to use system value*)
- mousewheel.withnokey.numlines = 1 (*The lowest scroll possible*)

If it's still fast, also change:

- mousewheel.withnokey.action = 4 (*Scroll using pixels, not lines*)

Reference: http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Mousewheel.