# Why does the mouse scroll speed go crazy after booting Windows, and why does unplugging it and plugging again fix the issue?

Tags: linux, multi-boot, mouse, scroll-wheel

I'm using a Microsoft wireless keyboard+mouse combo and I mainly use Arch Linux.

Whenever I boot MS Windows on my computer, when going back to Linux, my mouse scroll wheel is insanely fast.

Apparently, this is a common issue, as is also widely known [(1)](https://askubuntu.com/a/360045/495331) [(2)](https://askubuntu.com/a/172668/495331) [(3)](https://superuser.com/a/494676/358758) [(4)](https://superuser.com/a/723880/358758) that unplugging the usb receiver and plugging it again will solve the problem. I can confirm this works. Upon search, we can see that this is not restrict to Microsoft hardware, but Logitech and others as well.

The question is **WHY**? What is the explanation?

I use full disk encryption for my Linux system, including the boot partition. This rules out the hypothesis that Windows is interfering with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Microsoft mice need to be reset when you dual boot between Windows and Linux... This is a known issue, and there is even a utility to fix it...

> This program basically just resets a setting in the mouse through usb communication and then exits.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/resetmsmice/

Search "resetmsmice" and your distro, and there's probably a package already made to fix this ;-)

Arch Package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/resetmsmice

[image: screenshot of resetmsmice]